# C# Image load from the Project Image folder Image not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bitmap

I just save a image in my project folder in the same function I am calling that image, but the problem is that I am getting error **Image not found error.**
[image]

```
// Saving image in my project folder.....

** I have the image in my project folder 1.jpg** 

string imageFilePath = @"~/Images/1.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);  //load the image file
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 17))
    {
        graphics.DrawString(images.UperName, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
        graphics.DrawString(images.LowerName, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
    }
}

bitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
```

Comment: What's the file path of your image?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` ....

Comment: It's in my project folder Images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the virtual path "~/Images/1.jpg" in the file system. As leppie said, you should use Server.MapPath to convert the virtual path "~/Images/1.jpg" to physical path like "C:\filepath\filename.ext".

Comment: Thats work now getting this error when it try to save bitmap file  "{"A generic error occurred in GDI+."}"